# Unit testing Javascript - Jasmine test fails although code is working as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, typeerror, netbeans-8

I'm trying to get started with unit testing with javascript. I'm using jasmine framework 2.5.2 and Netbeans 8.2 as my IDE.

This is the simple code i want to test:

```
var ListHandler = {

    "reverseList": function (inputList) {
        var list = inputList,
            reversedList = [],
            length = list.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            reversedList.push(list[length - i - 1]);
        }

        return reversedList;
    },

    "sumUp": function (inputList) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
            count += inputList[i];
        }

        return count;
    },

    "concatenate": function (inputList1, inputList2) {
        var result = inputList1.concat(inputList2);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
describe("List Handler", function(){ 

   it("should return reversed List",function(){ 
      expect(ListHandler.reverseList([1,2,3])).toEqual([3,2,1]); 
   }); 

   it("should return sum of list values",function(){ 
      expect(ListHandler.sumUp([1,2,3])).toEqual(6); 
   }); 

   it("should return concatenated List", function(){
       expect(ListHandler.concatenate([1,2],["a","b"]).toEqual([1,2,"a","b"]));
   });
});
```

So when i run the test, the first two methods pass, but i get an error for the last method "concenate":

> TypeError: ListHandler.concatenate(...).toEqual is not a function

However, when i just execute it like `alert(ListHandler.concatenate([1,2,5], ["a", "b", "c"]));` it works fine. Can someone explain to me why jasmine complains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced closing paranthesis.

Try;

```
  expect(ListHandler.concatenate([1,2],["a","b"])).toEqual([1,2,"a","b"]);
```